# Should I have asked this question here instead of on meta.math?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Ad URLs should not use path nested under stackexchange.com (but maybe a subdomain instead)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30514/284627)

I asked that question on meta.math because I thought advertisement behavior was community-specific, and it's about an ad that showed up in the math community.

If that question makes more sense on this meta than that one then should that question be moved here (by a moderator), or should I create another question here on meta?

Comment: Both support and bug questions can go on the per-site meta. It is not for every user a must to know the existence of Meta Stack Exchange. That said: some questions in that topic work better here because you're more likely to find users on this very site that are familiar with SE network wide features. So audience is a criteria. I think that question did fine on that meta and looking at the answer, it shouldn't be here.

Comment: I've written answers Meta Stack Overflow when it comes to site-recommendations and with a bit of imagination my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370664/578411) might apply to this case as well.